# how to push data into particular object using angularjs?

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs

I have added my code. I have list of mobile stores with latitude and longitude. Here I have calculated distance between particular point to all stores and I am displaying in console but i want to push that value (`_d`) to every store. Please some one help me out.

Currently, it is just displaying:

```
Adtiya Samsung Store
aditiya@gmail.com

sri shakthi mobile service
rajs@gmail.com

sun mobile service center
sprtive23@gmail.com

ragu mobile service center
super@gmail.com
```

Please some one help me out to update this S_clocation. I am struggling here because I am new to this technology.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/16/

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
    //$scope.query = " Regular Service,Hardware Faults,overall maintenance";
    $scope.dealers = [{
        
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.93489905",
  S_Longitude: "77.57070772",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
       
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.9599264",
  S_Longitude: "77.5924983",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
        
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.911229",
  S_Longitude: "77.519281",
  S_clocation:""
  },
 {
        
        S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.909999",
  S_Longitude: "77.506871",
  S_clocation: ""
  }
    ]
 var _lat1 =12.904778 ;
 var _lon1 =77.585680;
 
              var d = $scope.dealers.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {



                            var _lat2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Latitude;
                            var _lon2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Longitude;

                            //--------------------------------------distance calculation-------------------------------------
                            function _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                                var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in kilometers
                                var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
                                var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
                                var a =
                                    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                                    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                                var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                                var d = R * c; // Distance in KM
                                return d;
                            }

                            function deg2rad(deg) {
                                return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
                            }



                            // precise value
                            var _d = "Precise value: " + _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2);




                            _d = Math.round(_getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2) * 100) / 100;

       console.log(_d);

                            

                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        }
 }
)
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <label>Case sensitive Search on Label</label><br>
        <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
        
        
            <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
                          
                {{dealer.Store_Name}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_Email_id}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_clocation}}<br>
    </div><br><br><br>
    
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a reference to your dealer object in your loop: `$scope.dealers[i]`. Just add another property to that object.

```
$scope.dealers[i].distance = _d;
```

Then you can display it on your page the same way you are displaying other properties.

```
{{dealer.distance}}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/17/).